# I'm trying to find if more than one word exist from text file in my arraylist(GridWord)

Tags: java

```
int count = 0;
for (int i =0; i <8635; i++){
  
    try {
        line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("wordlist.txt")).get(i);
        if (GridWords.contains(line)){
            count++;
        }
        if (count > 1) { 
        ChoseRandomWord(randomword );
        RemoveTheSimilarLetters(randomword, letters25 );
        CreateTheGridContents(letters25, GridMap1, GridMap2);
        ValidationOfTheGrid(GridMap1, GridMap2);
        AskingTheUser(GridMap1, GridMap2);
        
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to check if what I did is the right way and why it kind of slow down the compiler when executing the program.

Comment: The first thing you do is to move the `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("wordlist.txt"))` **before** the loop. Currently your read the while file on every loop iteration.

Comment: You should also move the `if (count > 1) { ` outside the loop. Your want to count first and evaluate the counter after you're done counting, right?

Comment: Why is that loop there anyway? You don't seem to do anything with the counter variable `i` inside the loop. And why is its condition `i <8635`? What is the significance of that 8635 number?

Comment: the file has 8635 lines and yes I moved the if (count > 1) { outside the loop. I still have the performance issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
int count = 0;
List<String> lines;
try {
    lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("wordlist.txt"));
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    lines = Collections.emptyList();
    // or return;
}
for (int i =0; i < lines.size(); i++){
    String line = lines.get(i);
    if (GridWords.contains(line)){
        count++;
    }
}
if (count > 1) {
    ChoseRandomWord(randomword);
    RemoveTheSimilarLetters(randomword, letters25 );
    CreateTheGridContents(letters25, GridMap1, GridMap2);
    ValidationOfTheGrid(GridMap1, GridMap2);
    AskingTheUser(GridMap1, GridMap2);
}
```

This first counts the gridwords, then does the remaining logic. However your code is not doing anything with `count` other than making sure at least 2 words were found.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying it. I still have to do something about the second line for IOException

Comment: true, I left out the exception handling. The only thing that throws one is `readAllLines`. You have to decide what should happen when reading the file fails, i'll update the answer.